# Add cursorPaginate to collection

Tags: laravel

So, I have built a very detailed collection in Laravel to give me very specific and clean data in a format that works within my frontend. Now, forgetting that this will be a LOT of data, I needed to add paginate. As this is just going to be infinite scroll, I wanted to use `cursorPaginate`

Unfortunately, the code below does not allow it. The standard error of `Method Illuminate\Support\Collection::cursorPaginate does not exist`

How would I be best to refactor this to give me the data required AND give me cursorPaginate? I am completely open to changing some of it, I just do not know where best to start.

Thanks in advance!

````
return Activity::get()->groupBy('batch_uuid')->map(function ($batch) {
                return [
                    'description' => $batch->first()->description,
                    'uuid' => $batch->first()->batch_uuid,
                    'event' => $batch->first()->event,
                    'created_at' => $batch->first()->created_at,
                    'subject' => $batch->first()->subject_type::find($batch->first()->subject_id),
                    'activities' => $batch->map(function ($activity) {
                        return [
                            'item' => $activity->causer_type::find($activity->causer_id),
                        ];
                    }),
                ];
            })->sortByDesc('created_at')->values();  
    ```
````

Answer (score 0):

You should watch [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=trzwyMAmzE0&t=91s) from Laravel Daily. First method mentioned in this video he uses **LengthAwarePaginator** but you can try **CursorPaginator** for your purpose.

Comment: I would love to do either but neither one works with how this is currently structured